# Desktop wallpaper goes black while setting a wallpaper slide show

Tags: desktop-background, shotwell, gnome-tweaks, slideshow

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.Sometimes when I set a wallpaper slideshow using Shotwell the screen goes totally black and even if that isn't the case the wallpapers do not change on the time they were supposed to.
for example if I set them to change every hour they change every 5 seconds.

I checked the wallpaper.xml file in Shotwell directory but it seemed Ok.
I think Shotwell wallpaper slide show has a glitch while working with Tweaks because I needed to set wallpapers on scaled state.

Answer (score 1):

It took so much time for me but **re-login** is working for me now - I have to do it every time I change pictures or time, but it works.

So, **first of all**, try to set the desired slideshow and re-login or restart the system.
Only then, try to install `gnome-tweaks` (`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`).

---

Encountered problems:

- I wasn't able to do it because of missing dependencies, so I had to downgrade my `gnome-shell`. Then I installed missing `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` and finally `gnome-tweaks`.
- Also, after the shell downgrading, I lost my previous settings (commands to bring them back in brackets):

  - taskbar (`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`),
  - desktop icons (`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`).